# Get latitude and longitude from search box

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I know many thread discuss this but my code still doesn't work.

I'm using google places searchBox API.

My code:

```js
function initMap(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('peta'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 16
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Your Location.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }

    var input = document.getElementById('alamat');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    
    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });
    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
       
        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
                
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML(places.geometry.location.lat());
    });
}
```

link script:

```html
<script  async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=places"></script>
```

html:

```html
<div id="peta" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<input type="text" id="x" readonly="readonly" name="x">
```

i put `document.getElementById` on my textbox but it still doesn't show the latitude. Where i should put this code? 
in other thread:

```js
var location= places.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat();
```

but it's not working. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined`.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.  And `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` on this line`var input = document.getElementById('alamat');` (that isn't in the HTML provided).

Comment: oke. i'm sorry. i've update the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your element #x an input text box?

If so try:

```
 document.getElementById('x').value = places.geometry.location.lat();
```

That will add the latitude to the value of the input text box.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes it's a textbox. but i already tried that too. but it didn't work too. haha.
Does i put the code in a wrong place?

Comment: It doesn't look to be.  You want it to update when the map changes so you would need it to be within the listener.

What do you get if you do `console.log(places.geometry.location.lat());`?  I presume it is actually given a string value?

Comment: Is #x a text box or text area?

Comment: textbox. i've update the description.
i don't have "api key". is it important?

Comment: there is also an error :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Comment: The error is your issue then... can you try putting:

`document.getElementById('x').value = place.geometry.location.lat();` 

at the end of the `places.forEach()` and see what you end up with.  It looks as though `geometry` is not defined for `places`, however, it clearly is in the `forEach()` for `place`.  Give that a try and see what you end up with.  It may be worth storing the latitude in a variable til after the `forEach` is complete, and then passing it into the textbox.

Comment: hey man. IT WORKS. Great. thank you. you are a life saver. haha. 
but the error is still shown up. but the latitude is works.

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

I've solve the problem.

as @Dammeul said, i place the 

`document.getElementById('x').value = place.geometry.location.lat();`

inside of `places.forEach(function (place))`
Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It will convert the address into latitude and longitude and also show the address in the map with the marker..You have just add your map API key

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.684994, 90.35633099999995);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
  
 function showResult(result) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = result.geometry.location.lng();
 
 
}

function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
   
    address = address || 'Dhaka,Bangladesh';
   
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                callback(results[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('show');
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
});

</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 
<style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
<div>
   <div id="map" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
    <input type="button" id="show" value="Show" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
  <div>
        <p>Latitude:
            <input type="text" id="latitude" readonly />
        </p>
        <p>Longitude:
            <input type="text" id="longitude" readonly />
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { GoogleMap, LoadScript } = require("../../");
const ScriptLoaded = require("../../docs/ScriptLoaded").default;

const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "400px",
  width: "800px"
};

const center = {
  lat: 38.685,
  lng: -115.234
};

const onLoad = ref => this.searchBox = ref;

const onPlacesChanged = () => {
    
      x = this.searchBox.getPlaces()
      console.log(x[0]["geometry"]["location"].lat())
    
    
    }
    

<ScriptLoaded>
  <GoogleMap
    id="searchbox-example"
    mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
    zoom={2.5}
    center={center}
  >
    <StandaloneSearchBox
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onPlacesChanged={
        onPlacesChanged
      }
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
        style={{
          boxSizing: `border-box`,
          border: `1px solid transparent`,
          width: `240px`,
          height: `32px`,
          padding: `0 12px`,
          borderRadius: `3px`,
          boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
          fontSize: `14px`,
          outline: `none`,
          textOverflow: `ellipses`,
          position: "absolute",
          left: "50%",
          marginLeft: "-120px"
        }}
      />
    </StandaloneSearchBox>
  </GoogleMap>
</ScriptLoaded>
```

Hi, i tried this, and it works, i get the lat and long, I am using react+searchboxAPI please feel free to follow up, here is the documentation, I realised that you cant do x["geometry"]["location"].lat(), instead you'll need to iterate through each of the places that have been returned, to test it, I did
console.log( x[0]["geometry"]["location"].lat() )  just to get the first result.You can use the js map function or iterate through the array of 20 by using a for loop.. cheers

https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#!/StandaloneSearchBox/1